# Software recommendation for a tensor calculation

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, resource-recommendations, software

What is the best software/package to calculate

$$2R_{\alpha\mu\beta\nu}R^{\mu\nu}-\nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta R + \Box R_{\alpha\beta}-\frac12g_{\alpha\beta}\Big(R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}-\Box R\Big)$$

for a non-diagonal metric?

I know the last term can be calculated by Maxima GPL, but what about the first three?

Comment: I do this type of thing with standard Mathematica - not sure how useful that is for you though. In the end it's just Christoffel symbols and partial derivatives.

Comment: The diffgeo package from Matt Headrick (found here - https://people.brandeis.edu/~headrick/Mathematica/index.html) is absolutely amazing at doing tensor calculations.

Comment: @Prahar It seems an interesting one. Tanx.

Answer (score 1):

The free Mathematica package [`xTensor`](http://xact.es/xTensor/) can perform calculations such as this.  You will also need to companion package `xCoba`, assuming that your goal is to get the components of this expression in a component basis.

Mathematica itself is, of course, very much *not* free.  But many institutions have a site license, and if you're at such an institution then this is not as much of an issue.

Comment: You can also purchase a student edition of Mathematica for a lower price. (At least you could a few years ago.) That is what I purchased when I retired in 2019.